# Como deixar só a primeira letra maiúscula de cada paragrafo?

Tags: php

No campo textarea, se o usuário digitar tudo misturado (maiúsculas e minusculas) em vários parágrafos, **preciso que só a 1ª letra de cada parágrafo fique maiúscula**.

Se usar o ucfirst(strtolower($texto)); somente a 1ª letra fica maiúscula de toda a string

**como fazer no php antes de gravar?**

Agradeço antecipadamente a ajuda dos colegas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resposta:**

Html (index.html):

```html
<form method="post" action="teste.php">
    <textarea name="texto" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP (teste.php):

```php
// Recebe o texto da <textarea>
$texto = (isset($_POST['texto'])) ? $_POST['texto'] : null;

// Transforma os parágrafos em itens de um array
$texto = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $texto));
// Percorre todos os itens do array (todos os paragrafos)
foreach($texto as &$paragrafo){
// Transforma a primeira letra em maiúscula
    $paragrafo = ucfirst(strtolower($paragrafo));
}

// Para ver como ficou o array (Cada item do array é um paragrafo)
print_r($texto);

// Cria um novo array para o foreach
$texto1 = $texto;
// Variável que irá armazenar o texto denovo como string
$novoTexto = "<br><br><br>";
// Percorre todo o array
foreach($texto1 as $valor){
    // Concatena os itens do array em uma sting
    $novoTexto .= "<p>".$valor."</p>";
}
// Mostra o resultado
echo $novoTexto;
```

Comment: Está gravando a palavra "Array". Só tirei o print_r($texto). Obrigado

Comment: Acabei de fazer o teste aqui, esta funcionando corretamente. O "problema" de estar gravando a palavra array é porque como mencionei na primeira linha de código, transformo a string da <textarea> em um array, onde cada paragrafo é um item, para visualizar o array você deve usar justamente o print_r(), justamente a parte que você tirou... Vou editar a resposta e colocar ainda mais mastigadinho...

Comment: Resolvi com implode. Postei como resposta. A sua ajuda serviu para eu pesquisar e ampliar os horizontes. Obrigado

Comment: Boa alternativa o implode para transformar o array em string novamente. Dei uma olhadinha na resposta que você postou, somente a titulo de curiosidade, o & de &$paragrafo não é mais necessário pois não haverá alteração no array durante o foreach. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Solução com base na ajuda do MichellHenrique

Usei Implode

```
// Transforma os parágrafos em itens de um array
$texto = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $texto));
// Percorre todos os itens do array (todos os paragrafos)
foreach($texto as &$paragrafo){
   // Transforma a primeira letra em maiúscula 
   $todos = $todos.ucfirst(strtolower($paragrafo)); // agrupa o explode em $todos 
}   
$texto = implode('', array ($todos)); // remonta o texto correto
```